# Regex for validating correct input for calculator

Tags: java, regex

I need to have some Calculator done, currently i'm dealing with the issue that I need to have only numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and operators (+, -, *, /, .) in my JTextField which is the user's input.

Currently my regex is like:
`String REGEX = "^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,1}$";`  and it's from an example that I found over the web.

How do I have also to possibility to allow these operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`? (the dot is already done)

The total idea is to have it like the Windows Calculator. 
I'm not that strong in this topic, please advice.

**EDIT:** it also needs to have round braces like `(` and `)`

Comment: what do you mean by "How do I having also to possibility to have the operators (+, -, *, /) ?"

Comment: They are like String, so I also need them to be printed in my `JTextField`

Comment: Are you validating the format of the input or if the input can be evaluated?

Comment: It's being typed by the user, so he can only type 0-9 and +-*/.  It's need to be the same like Windows Calculator .

Comment: why do you only admit zero or one decimal? `[0-9]{0,1}`. It's a must?

Comment: this is just an example from something over the we, feel free to do what you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that matches your requirements:

```
^[\d\+\/\*\.\- \(\)]*$
```

As a JAVA String this would be:

```
String regex = "^[\\d\\+\\/\\*\\.\\- \\(\\)]*$";
```

Note that I also added a SPACE to this list of allowed chars.

Comment: Can you please have also the numbers inside it ?

Comment: I guess, this also validates non-sense expressions  like `12.23/`, or `*()`. Maybe is ok to @RoeyGolzarpoor

Comment: \d is a representation for all numbers.
Since chars like '+' also have a meaning in regex, you need to escape them. Java then needs to escape '\' as well.

Comment: @Albert This is true. But dealing with all the possible input constellations would be over the top for a regex. This regex more or less deals only with the set of chars you put into that field.

Comment: @jHilscher. Yeah! You are right. I've been trying, but I didn't succeed ;)

Comment: Agree with jHilscher, if you want to go further write a function that validates the input. Interesting ideas are found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).

Comment: Most of these escapes are superfluous, `^[\\d+*/.()-]+$` is enough and much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody will need a bit more proper solution:

```
^(\d+[\+\-\*\/]{1})+\d+$
```

It is better because these strings won't pass:

```
45++6*6
12+4+
+2-6
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/zB7vV3/2

Comment: '+2-6' could be a valid expression. And '-2-2' won't pass ether.

Answer (score 0):

my regex

```
^[\d\(]+[\d\+\-\*\/\(\)]+[\d\)]+$
```

passed:

- 3+3*5*(2+1)

not good yet:

- 1+2)
- 1+)